# Passing parameter to crossstab in irepot

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created one *JasperReports*'s report  in iReport designer. I have added one crosstab to it and added one data source which contains one parameter.

When I run the report the value from prompt is not passed to query and result is not displayed accordingly in crosstab.

I have created same parameter in main report, datasource and crosstab. But its simply not passing to query in datasource.

**Question:** What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you mapped the data source to crosstab..

Actually you don't really require datasource for crosstab. You can directly write the query in main report and add parameter in main report itself.

Check that.It works fine for me without datasource.